# Access to Java library on Windows with Apache Cordova + Electron

Tags: java, windows, cordova, electron, interop

I am doing an Apache Cordova + Electron (with React/Redux) app. I have a requirement implying access to a java library already done, for a specific functionality. I think I could import the library to my project, but I don't know how to call it inside my app.
Is it even possible?

It is not possible to change this framework... at least, for now.

Comment: Can you please provide further details? a code snippets will increase the chances of getting help.

Comment: Hi MEDZ, i have not a example, but is like calling a "Hello World" done on Java, from a button on an app built on React/Electron/Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run java, you need to have JRE on the host machine. Hence try something like below:

1. Install JRE on the host machine (make sure that JRE is available).
2. RUN JAR file while starting your Cordova-electron application using electron's `child_process`.
3. Call the java API from the renderer process using javascript `fetch`.